Cannot find mpi.mod with OpenMPI from brew
! $UWHPSC/codes/mpi/test1.f90

program test1
    use mpi
    implicit none
    integer :: ierr, numprocs, proc_num

    call mpi_init(ierr)
    call mpi_comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, numprocs, ierr)
    call mpi_comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, proc_num, ierr)

    print *, 'Hello from Process number', proc_num, &
             ' of ', numprocs, ' processes'

    call mpi_finalize(ierr)

end program test1

I'm a Mac M1 user. I have to run the above code in a Mac terminal. I found an error that is mentioned below. I also installed open-mpi using brew install open-mpi, but I still encounter this problem.
MacBook-Air mpi % gfortran test1.f90 
test1.f90:4:9:

    4 |     use mpi
      |         1
Fatal Error: Cannot open module file 'mpi.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

MacBook-Air mpi % mpif90 test1.f90 
ld: warning: -commons use_dylibs is no longer supported, using error treatment instead


Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Please use the formatting features in the question editor to mark code and terminal output. I did these edits for you, together with some basic grammar edits.

compile with mpifort instead of gfortran

You show that you have it working with mpif90 test1.f90: this makes it less obvious to us what your question now is.
